# How to intercept HttpEntity from json response

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm using a Spring setup using the json mapping converters to send POJO classes as json back to the client.

E.g.:

```
@RequestMapping
@ResponseBody
public User getUser() {
    User user = getUser();
    return user;
}
```

This will return e.g. something like to the client:

```
{ 'username': 'My username', 'lastname': 'My lastname' }
```

I want to intercept all my controller actions to wrap the json in something like:

```
{
  'status': 200,
  'data': { 'username': 'My username', 'lastname': 'My lastname' }
}
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Why? The HTTP status will be part of the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can create a map like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getUser(){
    User user = new User();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("status", 200);
    map.put("data", user);
    return map;
}
```

For common usage, you can create a POJO

```
    public static class ResutInfo{
    private int status;
    private Object data;

   //get set}
```

then write the controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
@ResponseBody
public ResutInfo getUser2(){
    User user = new User();
    ResutInfo resutInfo = new ResutInfo();
    resutInfo.setStatus(200);
    resutInfo.setData(user);
    return resutInfo;
}
```

Comment: Yes this will work but then I would have to this in every controller. I'm looking for a more sophisticated implementation by e.g.  intercepting the response?

Comment: I have tried `HandlerInterceptorAdapter.postHandler()`. But it's not working. Because you can't get the Object return by controller methods. I think you shoule try to use AspectJ to handle the result.

Answer (score 0):

I find a possible solution for your question by extends `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

```
public class MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        //outputMessage.getHeaders().add("code", DigestUtils.md5Hex(object.toString()));
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("status", 200);
        map.put("data", object);
        super.writeInternal(map, outputMessage);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Then add your own conventer bean to spring-mvc config file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="com.xxx.utils.MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

This method does work for each `@ResponseBody` handler method.

**Note that** it changes default Spring action, you should think about it.

Comment: Thanks Larry, this seems the best way to intercept writting (or better converting) the response and adding stuff. /M

Comment: Although this works to add something to the response, the problem I can't get the actual response anymore. So also no way to set the status based on reponse' original status.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also do something like this

<mvc:annotation-driven>  <!-- this is added for validations to work -->
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
         <property name="objectMapper" ref="YourDtoWrapper"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="YourDtoWrapper" class="com.YourDtoWrapper"/>

inside your YourDtoWrapper class you can do something like this


public void writeValue(JsonGenerator jgen, Object value) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException {

        SomeDTO<Object> someDto = new SomeDTO<Object>("SUCCESS");//you can use an enum here
        someDto.setDto(value);//here dto is a property of someDTO

        super.writeValue(jgen, SomeDTO.getAsMap(someDto));
    }

this will give u result some thing like this

{
serviceResult: "SUCCESS"
context: null
dto: {
id: 1
firstName: "test"
lastName: "admin"
email: "admin@test.com"
phone: 1234
userName: "admin"
password: null
createdBy: "admin"
createdDate: null
statusId: 1
statusName: "ACTIVE"
organisationId: 1
organisationName: "test"
userTypeId: 1
userTypeName: "ADMIN"
roleIds: [0]
}
}
```